# Get robot position und orientation (in degree) from TF

Tags: ros, yaw, stampedtransform, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to get the Position (x, y) and the orientation from my robot. The position should be relative to the map TF. Therefore I used a TransformListener:

```
tf::StampedTransform transform_bot;
tf::TransformListener listener;

listener.lookupTransform("/map", "/base_footprint", ros::Time(0), transform_bot);

bot_x = transform_bot.getOrigin().x();
bot_y = transform_bot.getOrigin().y();

double roll, pitch, yaw;
transform_bot.getBasis().getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);

bot_dir = yaw * 180.0 / PI;

ROS_INFO("Bot X: %f", bot_x);
ROS_INFO("Bot Y: %f", bot_y);
ROS_INFO("Bot Z: %f", bot_dir);
```

So far I was not able to get good result with this solution...

Do you have any ideas, how to solve the problem?

Thank you,
Sebastian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241497/get-robot-position-und-orientation-(in-degree)-from-tf/) by [SeanAda](https://answers.ros.org/users/27721/seanada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure that `getBasis` does what you think, I could be wrong though. I would try using `getRotation` which returns a quaternion, then grabbing the yaw from that.

```
tf::Quaternion q = transform_bot.getRotation(); 
double yaw = tf::getYaw(q);
```

[Here](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a20a2050b55f2d88387ef0d9eea3ca749) is the `getYaw` documentation.

If that doesn't solve things could you edit your answer and describe what results you're observing with your current code?

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3